# Date difference calculation conditional on row entries

Tags: r, data.table

I have some event entries with event ID in one column, and event phases in another column, and the timestamps corresponding to each event id & phase.

There may be many phases for one event, some of them repeating at different times. My problem is to calculate the difference between the timestamps conditionally on those events. For example, for one event there is one entrance and then a phase2. Then 10 times phase 1 and again a phase2. The order and the number of the entries are changing from event to event, but entrance is always the first phase. For each event, I want to calculate the difference between phase2 and entrance, and then the difference between the subsequent phase2's.

I cannot find a fast working solution for this.

An example more or less looking like my original data frame,

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
#
sampleFrame <- data.frame(id = sample(c(1:1000), 5000, replace = TRUE),
                      phase = sample(c("entrance", "phase1", "phase2",  "phase3"), 5000, replace =TRUE),
                      date = sample(c(1439678910:1445678999), 5000, replace = TRUE))
#
setDT(sampleFrame)
#
sampleFrame <- sampleFrame %>% arrange(id, date)
#
sampleFrame[, date := as.POSIXct(date, origin ="1970-01-01")]
#
```

How can I conditionally calculate the time differences in data table / data frame way?

Comment: Please use a `set.seed`, the table I am getting has `phase2`'s after `entrance`s, and multiple `entrance`s for each ID... is that intended?

Comment: @mkemp6  Sorry for the late reply. It can get more than one entrance's but I filter those cases, in my real problem, too. For now, we can measure entrance-entrance, phase2-entrance, phase2-phase2. Thanks in advance!